# Why is rails giving me a SyntaxError in PostsController#index when I try and add a second model following the getting started guide for ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, syntax

Im new to programming and rails. Please be kind. I was following the getting started rails guide on how to build your first blog 
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html

Im up to the 6th part where I'm meant to add the comment model to the post model. After following the instructions, I'm getting this error.

```
    SyntaxError in PostsController#index
    /home/nadia/blog/app/models/post.rb:5: syntax error, unexpected ..., expecting ']' [...] 

    Extracted source (around line #4):

    def index 
     @post = Post.all
    end
```

This is my 
routes.rb

```
   1 Blog::Application.routes.draw do
   2
   3   
   5
   6   
   7   resources :posts
   8
   9   # You can have the root of your site routed with "root"
   10   root 'welcome#index'
   11
   12
   13   resources :posts do
   14       resources :comments
   15   end
```

this is my post_controller.rb

```
     1 class PostsController < ApplicationController
     2
     3   def index
     4     @post = Post.all 
     5   end
     6
     7   def new
     8     @post = Post.new
     9   end
     10   def create
     11     @ post = Post.new(params[:post].permit(:title, :text))
     12
     13     if @post.save
     14       redirect_to @post
     15     else
     16       render 'new'
     17     end
     18   end
     19
     20   def edit
     21     @post = Post.find(params[:id])
     22   end
     23
     24   def update
     25     @post = Post.find(params[:id])
     26
     27     if @post.update(params[:post].permit(:title, :text))
     28       redirect_to @post
     29     else
     30       render 'edit'
     31    end
     32   end
     33 
     34   def destroy
     35     @post = Post.find(params[:id])
     36     @post.destroy
     37
     38     redirect_to posts_path
     39   end
     40
     41   def show
     42     @post = Post.find(params[:id])
     43   end
     44
     45   private
     46  def post_params
     47       params.require(:post).permit(:title, :text)
     48     end
     49 end
```

comment_controller.rb

```
    1 class CommentsController < ApplicationController
    2   def create
    3     @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
    4     @comment = @post.comments.create(params[:comment].permit(:commenter,     :body))
    5     redirect_to post_path(@post)
    6   end
    7 end
```

and my index.html.erb

```
    1 <h1>Listing posts</h1>
    2 <%= link_to 'New post', new_post_path %>
    3 <table>
    4   <tr>
    5     <th>Title</th>
    6     <th>Text</th>
    7     <th></th>
    8   </tr>
    9 
    10
    11   <% @post.each do |post| %>
    12     <tr>
    13         <td><%= post.title %></td>
    14         <td><%= post.text %></td>
    15         <td><%= link_to 'Show', post %></td>
    16         <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_post_path(post) %></td>
    17         <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', post_path(post), method: :delete, data    : { confirm: 'Are you sure?'} %> </td>
    18     </tr>
    19    <% end %>
    20 </table>
```

Please help, and please let me know if I can supply additional information to help you help me.

Comment: I also get a similar error in PostsController#new

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the index method of the controller, you are using @post when you should be using @posts.  You have the same mistake on line 11 of index.html.erb.  @posts is a collection.  @post refers to a single post.

Comment: They are using it incorrectly, but also consistently, so this shouldn't be causing the problem described above

Comment: I just checked the git code for it. Looks like they use @posts = post.all

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo somewhere in your `app/models/post.rb` file, as you can tell from the error message.  It looks like you forgot to close a bracket.

Answer (score -1):

Yep. Got it. Thank you. I changed the line four code of the controller to

```
    @posts = Post.all
```

and then changed the index.html.erb file 
from

```
    <% @post.each do |post| %>
```

to

```
    <% @posts.each do |post| %>
```

I fixed the problem. Although I dont understand enough about ruby as to HOW i did it. I know some black magic happened and BAM. Thank you everyone.

Comment: tyler - You should vote up my answer and mark it as accepted. It's not black magic: The instance variable "@posts" is the collection of all Post objects; you display them all on the index page. The "@post" instance variable is used to create/edit/delete/update a single Post.

Comment: Also it looks like my suggestion is what solved the problem (judging by the fact that it is marked as correct), so not sure why you would want to downvote here.